# Hide Price Range from variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide the price range for variable products from only the single product page.
I tried the following Code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'lw_hide_variation_price', 10, 2);

function lw_hide_variation_price( $v_price, $v_product ) {

$v_product_types = array( 'variable');

if ( in_array ( $v_product->product_type, $v_product_types ) && !(is_shop()) ) {

return '';

}

return $v_price;

}
```

The price range on the home page will be hidden too.
How can I show the default variation price on home page and Shop page and keep the range hidden in single product page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ***woocommerce_variable_price_html*** hook instead